# pandas - remove duplicated rows in a MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to remove duplicated rows with the same multi-index from a `df`.

The multi-index are [latitude, longitude, AET_date].

```
                                                                    FFDI_daily_max
latitude                    longitude                   AET_date    
-39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    1972-01-20  1.20000004768371582031  
                                                        1972-01-21  0.89999997615814208984
                                                        **1972-01-22**  1.50000000000000000000
                                                        **1972-01-22**  1.40000000000000000000
                                                        1972-01-23  1.80000000000000000000
                                                        1972-01-24  1.40000000000000000000
... ... ... ...
-33.90000152587890625000    150.00000000000000000000    1972-01-20  1.10000004768371582031  
                                                        1972-01-21  0.49999997615814208984
                                                        **1972-01-22**  1.20000000000000000000
                                                        **1972-01-22**  1.10000000000000000000
                                                        1972-01-23  1.60000000000000000000
                                                        1972-01-24  1.60000000000000000000
```

There are duplicated rows in AET_Date for each (latitude and longitude). What I want to achieve is to remove the duplicated row and keep the row with the higher FFDI_daily_max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
df = df.max(level=[0,1,2], axis=0)
```

Or

```
df.sort_values('FFDI_daily_max').groupby(level=[0,1,2]).tail(1).sort_index()
```

Comment: `df = df.max(level=[0,1,2], axis=0)` works. Thanks.